# Module and package with same name

Tags: python, import, module, package

Can I have a package and a module with the same name in Python?

ex:

```
import json
import myapp.json.jsoncustommodule
```

I don't know if this has anything to do with the fact that json is in Python built-in library.

In most languages, this is acceptable. However, Python seems to confuse both things, even if they are in different parent packages.

Comment: What problem do you have exactly? The example you give works just fine. I suspect you have a problem with *local* names, the name under which an imported object is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, there's no issue with doing something like this in python.

However if you have a namespace conflict resulting from something like this:-

```
import json

from myspecialpackage import json
```

You will need to resolve it by using `as` keyword, like this:-

```
from myspecialpackage import json as special_json
```

Comment: You're right. I made a simple test example and it works fine. It must be something else.  In my code, if I print json.__file__, it returns myapp.json.__init__.py.  Any idea why?

Comment: You will also need to get your `sys.path` (`PYTHONPATH`) correct.

My sure that your `myspecialpackage` is in the `sys.path`, but behind your `site-packages` where python's built-in `json` module is.

Comment: The json dir was a subdir of the script dir... and the current script path comes before site-packages in python path. Problem solved.