# Use same name for module and package

Tags: python, naming-conventions

When developing in Python, I try to follow [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) conventions. So I use lower case for module (i.e. file) names and package (i.e. directories) names.

Most of the time, I end up with the same name.
For example, say I work on a calendar manager, I'll create a directory called `calendar_manager`[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232935/module-and-package-with-same-name) and put inside a file called `calendar_manager.py`.

This always bothers me a little when I then have to type `from calendar_manager import calendar_manager`, as I wonder if this is slightly wrong, or goes against the guidelines of the language. On the other hand, there is often one single name that makes sense to me for a project, and it seems natural to use it both for the package and module.

I notice few of the well known python packages do this. `datetime` is a notable exception, as both the package and module are called `datetime`, therefore needing to import it like this `from datetime import datetime`.

Is it recognized as good practice or not to have the same name for both? As I do not want to encourage subjective answers, can anyone point me to an authoritative source, or objective data that indicates one way or the other? I could not find anything on that specific point in [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232935/module-and-package-with-same-name) I know [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) does not encourage underscores for package names, but this has actually become accepted practice in the Python community. I find it clearer than juxtaposing words together, like `calendarmanager`

There are a few [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232935/module-and-package-with-same-name) on Stack Overflow on using the same name for module and package, but they address solving technical problems around it, not higher level discussion about naming conventions.

Comment: `datetime` has many elements `datetime.datetime`, `datetime.time`, `datetime.date`, `datetime.timedelta` and it keeps all in one file `datetime.py` as `class datetime`, `class time`, `class date`, `class timedelta` (without using folder) - so it looks different. But if you have other elements in module `calendar_manager` then `from calendar_manager import calendar_manager` seems OK. But if you have only `from calendar_manager import `calendar_manager.py` then maybe you could use `__init__.py` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python Enhancement Proposals (PEP)

A common theme across several **Python Enhancement Proposals** ***(PEP)*** to enforce the use of **all-lowercase** or **sneak_case** for names (packages, modules, functions, variables, etc.), so is the use of **underscores** being **usually discouraged** when **naming a package** as you too mentioned.

That doesn't mean that you need to use **fused lowercase** names like `calendarmanager` and/or stick with only using **descriptive** or **non-single** names for packages and modules alike.

Although it is **recommended** that one should **adhere** to using certain **PEP** conventions, it is also **advised** that **everyone should do whatever makes more sense according to their needs**, the same why reason people use **underscores** for package names **despite it being discouraged**.

---

### Same Name & Non-Single Names

Using the exact same name for a package and the module that's inside can, depending on the name and name length, make it difficult to read and remember every time.

If you decide to use non-single names, consider using a **shortname**:

```
import calendar_manager.calendar_manager as shortname
```

Add the same name again:

```
import calendar_manager.calendar_manager as calendar_manager
```

---

### Names, Cases & Examples

Names **should** have **meaning**, while also being **relatively simple**. Modules & packages should both have a **meaningfully** and **memorable** name, just like projects.

You have two names and nothing says they have to be the same length or the same case, you are free to choose what you feel makes more sense to you and your use case.

There are a plethora of different **supported case formats** available out there. Use them to **suit your needs**, not to hinder your progress.

Example using **snake_case** and **camelCase**:

```
Package name: “calendar_utils”
Module name: “calenderManager”

from calender_utils import calenderManager
```

A different example using **camelCase** and then **snake_case**:

```
Package name: “calendarUtils”
Module name: “calender_manager”

from calenderUtils import calender_manager
```

Example using **snake_case** and a **shorter name**:

```
Package name: “calendar_utils”
Module name: “manager”

from calender_utils import manager
```

Example using **camelCase** and a **shorter name**:

```
Package name: “calendarUtils”
Module name: “manager”

from calenderUtils import manager
```